# Stop a Thread that waits for a long period

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm having problems to terminate a thread that waits on `accept()` call.

`accept()`: Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made.

I have `GestorBuzon` which implements the `Runnable` interface:

```
public class GestorBuzon implements Runnable{

   private static volatile boolean running = true;

   public void run() {
       try {
           while (running) {
               -- pre code
               accept();
               -- post code
           }
       } catch(IOException e) {
             terminate();
       } 
   }

   public static void terminate() {
       running = false;
   }
}
```

And I have `MessageSystem` class which starts and stops the thread:

```
public class MessageSystem {

    private GestorBuzon gestorBuzon;
    private Thread thread;

    public MessageSystem() {
        // Starts the Thread
        contextInitialized();
    }

    private void contextInitialized() {
        gestorBuzon = new GestorBuzon();
        thread = new Thread(gestorBuzon);
        thread.start();
    }

    private void contextDestroyed() {
        if (thread != null) {
            gestorBuzon.terminate();
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                gestorBuzon.terminate();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

I call the `accept()` function in `Runnable` class multiple times, but when I use `contextDestroyed()` function, the Thread is still waiting on `accept()` and the Thread doesn't terminate. What am I doing wrong?

It have to do this:
[image]

Comment: Can you interrupt your threads to stop them waiting on `accept()`?

Comment: This Runnable class its a listener of connections, and when I dont want to do more **accept()** (connections from a client), I use **contextDestroyed()**. I don't know other form to terminate it properly.

Comment: Call `thread.interrupt()` after `gestorBuzon.terminate()`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Methods of `java.net` are not interruptible.

Comment: Have you tried using the destroy() method? It can kill the thread

Comment: Thread.destroy() is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a socket timeout on the `ServerSocket` via `setSoTimeout()`, and catch `SocketTimeoutException`when it fires. You can then inspect your `running` flag in the `catch` block etc. and decide whether to continue or stop accepting.

Comment: The problem is that I need to do **"X"** connections to the server, I dont know this number, and then I have to stop the Thread.

Comment: So clear your `running` flag when you get to *X* and proceed as above.

Comment: So I dont know how much long it will between 2 client connections. Maybe 1 seconds, maybe 1000 seconds. And if I put a **setSoTimeout(999999)** Can I switch timeout on **contextDestroyed()** metod to 0?..Also its not a good solution, the time is arbitrary

Comment: I put an image to show you what the program have to do.

Comment: Set a timeout that's the longest you're willing to wait before the thread shuts down. If the thread isn't being shut down, just call `accept` again. Alternatively, don't set a timeout. To shut down, set a "shutdown" flag and then force `accept` to unblock by making a connection yourself.

Comment: @MarioNavarroClaras How long between client connections is irrelevant. The question is how long you're prepared to wait when you're shutting it down. I'd suggest at least five seconds.

Comment: I got the ServerSocket on **contextDestroyed()** method and do a serversocket.close(). Is this a poor solution? I thought to do non-blocking mode.

Comment: Non-blocking mode is certainly no better and probably much worse than what I or @DavidSchwartz have suggested here.

Comment: @MarioNavarroClaras You can't do that. You can't release a resource in one thread while another thread is, or might be, using it. If the other thread has already called `accept` but has not yet blocked, the results are unpredictable. (Or if the other thread calls `accept` while the `close` operation is in progress.)

Comment: @MarioNavarroClaras It baffles me why you would ask about a third solution when you've already been given two perfectly good ones. Why post in the first place?

Comment: Yes I want to do this solution: **Alternatively, don't set a timeout. To shut down, set a "shutdown" flag and then force accept to unblock by making a connection yourself.** but dont know how to connect myself

Comment: The same way other people connect to you. You create a socket and call `connect`.